# Debug is not defined in Webpack

Tags: debugging, npm, webpack

***Bug report***
**What is the current behavior?**
When using `webpack --watch` or `npx webpack --watch --config webpack.config.js`

**If the current behavior is a bug, please provide the steps to reproduce.**
Debug is not defined after using `webpack --watch` or `npx webpack --watch --config webpack.config.js`

**What is the expected behavior?**
Any idea

**Other relevant information:**
webpack version: 4.12.1
Node.js version: 8.11.3
Operating System: Fedora 25/64 bits
Additional tools: jdotnet/.npm/_logs/2018-06-30T06_46_32_251Z-debug.log

**my log file**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok<br>
1 verbose cli [ '/home/jdotnet/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/node',<br>
1 verbose cli '/home/jdotnet/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/npm',<br>
1 verbose cli 'run',<br>
1 verbose cli 'watch' ]<br>
2 info using npm@5.6.0<br>
3 info using node@v8.11.3<br>
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewatch', 'watch', 'postwatch' ]<br>
5 info lifecycle helpscout@1.0.0prewatch: helpscout@1.0.0<br>
6 info lifecycle helpscout@1.0.0watch: helpscout@1.0.0<br>
7 verbose lifecycle helpscout@1.0.0watch: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true<br>
8 verbose lifecycle helpscout@1.0.0watch: PATH: <br>/home/jdotnet/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-<br>bin:/var/www/html/helpscout/node_modules/.bin:/home/jdotnet/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/jdotnet/.composer/vendor/bin:/home/jdotnet/.local/bin:/home/jdotnet/bin
9 verbose lifecycle helpscout@1.0.0watch: CWD: /var/www/html/helpscout<br>
10 silly lifecycle helpscout@1.0.0watch: Args: [ '-c', 'npx webpack --watch --config webpack.config.js' ]<br>
11 silly lifecycle helpscout@1.0.0watch: Returned: code: 1 signal: null<br>
12 info lifecycle helpscout@1.0.0watch: Failed to exec watch script<br>
13 verbose stack Error: helpscout@1.0.0 watch: npx webpack --watch --config webpack.config.js<br>
13 verbose stack Exit status 1<br>
13 verbose stack at EventEmitter. (/home/jdotnet/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:285:16)<br>
13 verbose stack at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)<br>
13 verbose stack at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)<br>
13 verbose stack at ChildProcess. (/home/jdotnet/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)<br>
13 verbose stack at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)<br>
13 verbose stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)<br>
13 verbose stack at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)<br>
13 verbose stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit <br>(internal/child_process.js:209:5)<br>
14 verbose pkgid helpscout@1.0.0<br>
15 verbose cwd /var/www/html/helpscout<br>
16 verbose Linux 4.13.16-100.fc25.x86_64<br>
17 verbose argv "/home/jdotnet/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/node" "/home/jdotnet/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/bin/npm" "run" "watch"<br>
18 verbose node v8.11.3<br>
19 verbose npm v5.6.0<br>
20 error code ELIFECYCLE<br>
21 error errno 1<br>
22 error helpscout@1.0.0 watch: npx webpack --watch --config webpack.config.js<br>
22 error Exit status 1<br>
23 error Failed at the helpscout@1.0.0 watch script.<br>
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.<br>
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]<br>
```

Comment: post this on webpack issues, best place to have

Comment: @MatheusSilva They close my issue on webpack issues .

Comment: try running a local version of webpack, instead of using npx

Comment: @MatheusSilva same problem when i start `webpack --watch`

Comment: Reopen an issue there, with a reproducible example. Allow them to show that this can be a bug. Keep spamming them, this is not a normal question by no means. This question won't be solved by stackoverflow